# White blok with hyperlink

Tags: css, wordpress, right-justified

Behind the hyperlink is a white block, this is not the intention, how can I fix this? The text is justified, and has a margin on the left side of 250 px.

http://tinyurl.com/nvvned7

hope someone can help

Gr Rogier

Comment: remove `padding-right:250px` from your **style.css** Line 79 and add `width:500px` instead of that.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `padding-right: 250px;` in your css rules for this anchor element:

```
.art-postcontent, .art-postcontent li, .art-postcontent table, .art-postcontent a, .art-postcontent a:link, .art-postcontent a:visited, .art-postcontent a.visited, .art-postcontent a:hover, .art-postcontent a.hovered {
    font-family: Arial,"Arial Unicode MS",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    padding-right: 250px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Specifically in this case, the following part of the css selectors triggers the application of the css rule on your anchor:

`.art-postcontent a, .art-postcontent a:link, .art-postcontent a:visited, .art-postcontent a:hover`

You can resolve the issue in two possible ways.

1) Either remove this rule - which probably is not a good idea since it might be necessary on other anchors.

2) Add a css class to your anchor element that overwrites this padding-right:

```
.my-link {
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

along with

```
<a href="#" class="my-link">Anouk@Work BV.</a>
```

Also, I noticed you wrap your links in a `<span style="text-decoration: underline;">`-tag. This is not necessary, the inline css rule used here should be applied directly to the anchor element.

I **strongly** recommend you learn the very basics of html and css.

Comment: Thanx, is am still an beginner with css. But it is very usefull